# Weird behaviour HTML accented character

Tags: mysql, utf-8, character-encoding, zend-framework2, diacritics

I use zf2 with doctrine.

My problem:

```
echo $this->escapeHtml($myobj->__get('name'));
```

where 'name' is stored in mysql and contains an accent, like "automàtica", I obtain the correct "automàtica" string on the web.

But if I try:

```
echo $this->translate("àòùì")
```

I obtain:

```
����
```

Same result if I do not translate anything in the view:

```
<p>àòùì</p>
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
```

How I can resolve to view the correct "àòùì" witohut replace the utf8 letters with the code like é etc...?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are your ***source code files*** actually saved as UTF-8...?

Comment: Thanks so much... Today I'm so tired..... -_- Now I need to convert encoding for any file on Eclipse

Comment: Black diamonds usually means that you had latin1 text and stored it using `SET NAMES latin1` (or equivalent).